# Pertaining to The Martian, what is the ratio of SOLs to Earth days?

Tags: the-martian

I didn't see an explanation in the movie. How many days pass on Earth when one SOL passes on Mars?

I heard a reference of two months passing, but I thought only (counts)....less than 50 SOLs had passed.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timekeeping_on_Mars *The Martian* is based on actual science (largely)... so a Sol in the book is the same as an actual Martian Sol.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The physics of Mars in *The Martian* is identical to the actual physics of the planet, as such, we only need to know the *actual* length of a Martian sol (in hours/minutes) to know how it compares with an Earth day.

A [Martian day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timekeeping_on_Mars) is nearly identical to an Earth day. There's only a difference of about 2.7% between the two.

> The average length of a Martian [sidereal day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidereal_day) is 24h 37m 22.663s (88,642.66300 seconds based on SI units), and the length of its solar day (often called a sol) is 24h 39m 35.244147s (88,775.244147 seconds). The corresponding values for Earth are 23h 56m 4.0916s and 24h 00m 00.002s, respectively. This yields a conversion factor of 1.02749125170 days/sol. Thus Mars' solar day is only about 2.7% longer than Earth's.

The number above you're interested in is the solar day - 24 hours, 39 minutes, 35 seconds.

Comment: Isn't the number they are interested in 1.02749125170 since they are looking for the ratio?

as in 1:1.02749125170

Comment: "There's only a difference of about 2.7% between the two." Not to humblebrag, but I had a great opportunity to work on a Mars mission when I was in college (my avatar photo is from this mission). A difference of "only" 40 minutes/day for a 90 sol mission meant that every sol's work begins at 8:00am, then 8:40am, ..., 8:00pm, etc. I lived in 3 straight months of perpetual jet lag. Great experience, but would not want to repeat shifting my schedule daily by 40 minutes!

Comment: @DangKhoa for some people (most notably 'evening people'), the increased day length is actually beneficial.

Comment: *I need to create calories. And I need enough to last the 1387 sols until Ares 4 arrives. If I don’t get rescued by Ares 4, I’m dead anyway. **A sol is 39 minutes longer than a day**, so it works out to be 1425 days.*  -  from Chapter 3, `LOG ENTRY: SOL 25`